# How i can put multiple times in this script

Tags: javascript, python

i need know how i can put a my code in python to execute in diff times like one time 5 min and other in 7 min

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:  
        main()  
        time.sleep(720)  # 12 Min
```

This is the part of the script that contains the time it will send, it is done in seconds, so if I put the number 60 it will be 1 minute, but I wanted to know how I can make this script run at different times, for example One time it runs in 500 seconds and another time in 800 seconds, could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Whitespace in python is important.  Format your code correctly if you expect anyone to read it or offer help.

Comment: now i put entire code

Comment: The question isn't very clear, are you talking about `time.sleep(720)`? You can make the argument a variable that you can change.

Comment: You could put the value in the `config.json` file.

Comment: in config.json just got the pass and email of the acc

Comment: dotn got important thigs

Comment: You could do something like have a list of times and have a counter that selects an item in the list to feed to the sleep method.  If you use modulo division of the counter and assign it to itself by the length of the list you can loop through the list over and over again.

Comment: i am new with codes, i want know how i can add two times

Comment: like onee time he send a mensage in 500 seconds and other time he send mensage in 800 seconds

Comment: You could call your script with an argument and use sys.argv[x] (where x is the position of the argument). Ex: `python3 main.py 800` and then in your script - Ex: `time = sys.argv[1]`

Comment: u can put it in script im new with it i dont know very well?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply prompt the user for a time. This will allow you to change the duration every time before it runs. The one drawback to this method is: It won't do anything until the user inputs a duration... every time.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    while True:    
        while not (t := input('Input a duration in seconds: ')).isdigit():
            print('Value must be numeric. Try Again.')
        main()      
        time.sleep(int(t))
```

---

Another way is to call your script with args. This solves the problem of your script being blocked by a prompt, but will keep using the same duration until the script is run with a new argument.

`python3 main.py 800`

And add the below to your script

```py
import sys

duration = 720 #12 minute default

#overwrite duration if possible
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    if (t := sys.argv[1]).isdigit():
        duration = int(t)

# represents most of your code

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    while True:    
        main()      
        time.sleep(duration)
```

Comment: Can it be automated? causing it to ask me for the seconds again after running a few times?

Comment: @rogerio - You can make it do whatever you want. However, expecting me to keep redeveloping this for you is not realistically going to happen. I answered your question with 2 possible solutions. Assert some diligence and modify one of them to your needs.

Comment: how i can delete i question i alredy solved it with other method

Comment: @rogerio - then you should answer your question with your solution. This is why I don't answer questions by users with super low reputation. I spent 20ish minutes helping you. I've been upvoted for my answer, and now you want to delete it. Explain why helping new people is worth it. You're going in the "never help" list.